# How many Callable objects are there?

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

Could someone help me to solve this task:

You are given a Callable object. Some say that it returns another Callable object. And that Callable returns another Callable object! And so on. You should find out how many Callable objects there are. Write a method that solves this problem.

I don't know what does the "last" Callable return, maybe not "null".

````
    public static int determineCallableDepth(Callable callable) {
        return countCallable(0, callable);
    }

    public static int countCallable(int countCallable, Callable callToCount) {
        if (callToCount == null) {
            return countCallable;
        }
        try {
            return countCallable(countCallable + 1, (Callable)callToCount.call());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return countCallable;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Have you tried anything (like creating a caalable without another callable and calling the call-method on that object)?

Comment: I tried my code on this Callable, it returns 1: Callable callable1 = new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        };

Comment: I believe that your code is sufficient to give you the correct answer. Is there any more specific questions you want to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code for this task.

```
public static int determineCallableDepth(Callable callable) {
    Object temp = null;
    try { 
        temp = callable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return temp instanceof Callable ? 1 + determineCallableDepth((Callable) temp) : 1;
}
```

I think that you don't need any clarification :D

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I thought about instanceof, but couldn't handle with try/catch block.